# How do I `git reset` in a worktree?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-worktree

I've noticed that if I try to `git reset` on a secondary worktree, it resets based on the *primary* worktree.

Suppose I have *master (d)* checked out on my normal repo, and have *feature (f)* in my separate worktree.  If I do `git reset --hard head~1` I end up at *c* rather than *e* as I would expect:

```
master   _______a______c__d
feature          \__b________e__f
```

I've tried looking for how to correctly reset in a worktree, but have been unable to find anything.

Comment: If `HEAD~1` is `c` then `HEAD` must be `d`. Maybe you typed the command in the wrong directory?

Comment: Thanks, but no, I was definitely in the right directory, as it breaks my worktree but my normal repo is unchanged.
I've just discovered that using the name of the branch seems to work: `git reset --hard feature~1` but I'd appreciate confirmation that this is the correct way to do it!

Comment: Did you spell it `head` in lowercase? That would cause the problem if you are on Windows or MacOS, typically. (Some like to use `@` to avoid this)

Comment: Yup, uppercase worked too, thanks! What's the correct syntax for using `@` - I've not seen it used before.

Comment: @torek - if you add this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here is that you are on a case-folding system (typical of a MacOS or Windows setup, but not for Linux setups) and you used `head` (lowercase) instead of `HEAD` (all uppercase).

When you do this in the main work-tree of a repository, it works anyway.  But when you do this in an added work-tree, it fails: `head` resolves to the tip commit of the branch in the *main* work-tree, rather than the tip of the branch in your current work-tree.  For instance, if you are in a work-tree working on `feature` while the main work-tree has `master` checked out, `HEAD~1` means `feature~1` but `head~1` means `master~1`.

If you don't like typing out `HEAD` in all uppercase, you can use the `@` symbol where you would have used `HEAD`.  For instance, `@~1` means the same thing as `HEAD~1`; `git reset --hard @` means the same thing as `git reset --hard`; and so on.

Comment: Using `@~1` doesn't seem to work - I get the error: `Unrecognized token in source text`

Comment: Curious. It works fine for me: `git rev-parse @~1` => `54041832d7d2a20c26bdf8eeb8aeb475024ef8d5`. ... Aha, this is a Powershell issue: powershell itself is interpreting one or more of these characters.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Escaping the @ works: either `\`@~1` or `'@~1'`

Answer (score 1):

Using the name of the branch seems to do what I expected: `git reset --hard feature~1`